# Break statement not taking me outside of loop java

Tags: java, loops, break

I am solving this problem on code forces.
https://codeforces.com/contest/1675/problem/B

The `break` statement I have doesn't break out of the `while` loop.
When I use this input:

[image: input]

It outputs `-1` one twice in the same case, which shows that the `break` statement isn't taking me outside the loop?

Why is this happening?

```
public class vanita {
    
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cases = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
            boolean test = true;
            int arrLength = in.nextInt();
            int arr[] = new int[arrLength];
            for (int j = 0; j < arrLength; j++) {
                arr[j] = in.nextInt();
            }
            int operations = 0;
            int after;
            for (int j = arrLength-1; j >= 1 ; j--){
                
                after = arr[j-1];
                
                while (arr[j] <= after) {
                    arr[j-1] = (int)Math.floor(arr[j-1]/2);
                    after = arr[j-1];
                    operations++;
                    if (arr[j] == 0 && arr[j-1] == 0) {
                        //System.out.println("current: " + arr[j]);
                        //System.out.println("after: " + arr[j-1]);
                        //System.out.println("Case " + i);
                        System.out.println("-1");
                        test = false;
                        break;
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int s = 0; s < arrLength; s++) {
                //System.out.print(arr[s] + " ");
            }
            //System.out.println(" ");
            if (test == true) {
                System.out.println(operations);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember not to show [pictures of text](/help/how-to-ask), just put the text in your post with appropriate markup. Also, explain the problem in your post: a link to where the exercise can be found is fine but only _in addition_ to explaining the problem in your post. Think of it this way: if the rest of the internet turns into a 404, your post should still make sense.

Answer (score 0):

i think it breaks out of the inner while loop, but not the outer for loop. So the inner while loop runs multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

### Problems

Normally a `break;` will always break out of the most recent loop. If you can't break out of your loop, the problem is your algorithm or your condition.

### Solutions

First, always debug to see if you enter your if statement.

Second, use something else as condition of your while loop. You could use a boolean and change its value to break the while condition. Ex:

```
boolean hasFoundDuplicate = false;
while(!hasFoundDuplicate){
    arr[j-1] = (int)Math.floor(arr[j-1]/2);
    after = arr[j-1];
    operations++;
    if(arr[j] == 0 && arr[j-1] == 0){
        hasFoundDuplicate = true;
    }
}
```